# flask html input format

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to read a file in using python/Flask and display it at the click of a button. To view the file, a return function like this works fine:

```
return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))
```

But I am trying to implement in HTML to view file at a click. Something like this:

```
<form><input action="redirect(url_for etc. ??)" type=submit value=viewFile> </form>
```

What would be the correct syntax for `action`?
Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action attribute should go on `<form>`, not `<input>`. The value of action should just be the URL of your route which accepts the file. Assuming you're using Jinja2, something like this:

Jinja2:

```
<form action="{{url_for('upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="view_file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    # Handle upload and save to disk here..
    return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
```

See also http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/ (it looks like you are already working from that example..)

Comment: I am trying to have a page that the user can confirm the file is read. Like this:

python:

...
return render_template('view.html')

HTML (view.html):

<!doctype html>
<form action="{{redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',filename=filename))}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=submit value='view file'>
</form>

When I press 'view file' I get an error, 

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
UndefinedError: 'redirect' is undefined

How should action be written to redirect the file address?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me to pass filename to html form input.

python:

```
...
return render_template('view.html', cat = filename)
```

html (view.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<form action="{{url_for('uploaded_file', filename=cat)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=submit value='view file'>
</form>
```